# jquery submit - change input value before post

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to change the value of an input textbox before submitting a form using something like the following:

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
     $('#MyTextBox').val('test');
});
```

However, when debugging the btnSubmit_Click method on the server side, both Request.Form[MyTextBox.UniqueID] and MyTextBox.Text contain the "old" value of #MyTextBox.  It appears that the form is being submitted before the javascript completes running.  Any idea why this is happening?  The javascript definitely runs because if I add an alert, it pops up.  If instead of using the form submit function, I use the click button, it works and the new value gets posted to the server:

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
     $('#MyTextBox').val('test');
});
```

The submit button is defined as:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"
Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="submitRequest" />
```

Also on a separate note, is it better practice to use Request.Form[MyTextBox.UniqueID] or MyTextBox.Text in the server side method or does it not matter?

Comment: Make sure your original code has `);` at the end. Guess it's just a copy-paste issue in your post...

Comment: yes correct, just a c/p issue, but thx for checking

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what this has todo with asp.net, but this jquery works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pTuL5/.

```
$('#MyForm').submit(function ()
{
    $('#MyForm input[name="q"]').val('test');
    $('#MyForm').submit();
    return false;
});
```

Tell me how it goes

Comment: Same issue, I see the value change on the page, but the new value is not included in the post

Comment: Hm, for me it was, could you post up your entire page?

Comment: Would be difficult to paste the whole thing.  However, I have noticed a few points:
1) Instead of using "$('#form1').submit(function () {", using "$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {" works but I'd prefer not to use that method per my original question
2) With the submit method, if I put an alert in the function and a breakpoint on the server side code, the server side breakpoint gets hit before I click ok to the alert.  This makes me think the form is getting submitted before the javascript fully runs

Comment: The suggested code will drop the key-value pair of the submit button from the request - if that is relevant, it'll break serverside logic.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, but dont set button type "submit".

```
function submitButton() {
    $('#field').val('sdasdasd');
    $('#form').submit();
    return false;
}
```

And if using your way, but I dont think it will work.

```
$('#form1').submit(function () {
    $('#MyTextBox').val('test');
    $('#fomr1').submit();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have some javascript error on the page load. Make sure there are no js errors and below code in executed on page load.

```
$(function(){

    $('#MyForm').submit(function ()
    {
        $(this).find('input[name="q"]').val('test');
        return true;
    });

});
```

Comment: There's no js errors, I can see the value in the textbox change on the actual page, it's just not included in the post results

Comment: He is right, that could be the problem, try putting an alert in your submit function, see if it comes up

Comment: Yep already tried, alert comes up so the code is being called, I also see the lines getting hit in firebug.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$('#form1').one('submit', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#MyTextBox').val('test');
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

let me know..

Comment: I tried that as well, no luck.  There must be something else going on in my code that is causing the post to occur before the javascript runs - perhaps a conflict with naming, masterpages, or updatepanels.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the element ( input ) that you want to change is not disabled, if it is disabled then the original value will be sent but if it is enabled the new value will be sent in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use submit() in the onSubmit() function handler. Just do what you want to do and "return true" will submit the form:

(On document ready)

```
$('#yourform').submit(function()
            {
                $("#yourInputYouWantTochange").prop('checked', true); //If radio or checkbox
                $("#yourInputYouWantTochange").val('whatever'); //If something else
                return true;                
            });
```